# What factors affect the threshold voltage in MOSFETs?

Tags: transistors, mosfet, layout, matching

Does orientation of the MOSFET devices on a chip affect the threshold voltage similarity (matching?)

What are the factors affected by different orientation.
[image]

Comment: If it did then placement towards north might result in a different characteristic if placed east, west or south.

Comment: Perhaps if you were more specific about what you mean by "orientation".  It's very unclear what you are asking.

Comment: @jwh20 I added a photo for more details , i know that it's better be the first case where they both have the same orientation (vertical), but i want to know if it affcets the VTH between them or not and how? Thanks for response

Comment: You might want to study: http://ims.unipv.it/Courses/download/AIC/Layout02.pdf

Comment: I was also once wondering why some MOSFET has high Vgs(th), while some has low. So I googled for a text book to read. I found RC Jaeger's Microelectronics Circuit Design's the best for newbies. There is a free eBook of 4th Edition. I spent about 30 hours reading the first 4 chapters and happily got a vague idea of the MOSFET parameters, including Vgs(th) etc. Jaeger uses a mathematical model to explain things, and I think we cannot explain MOSFET stuff without using equations.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, it does. There are two factors at work here. The first is the inherent variability of the manufacturing processes across the surface of the wafer, but that tends to be of concern only over large areas.

The second is called **chirality**. An example of this in everyday life is having a right hand and a left hand. As a consequence, a glove for the left hand is different from a glove for the right hand.

The source/drain regions are formed by ion implantation into the wafer, **after** the gate has been deposited. The direction of the ions is not always orthogonal to the surface of the wafer...like rain coming down in a wind. The relatively tall transistor gate material can cause shadows in the deposition, leading to small variations in behavior of the transistors.

Also, the etch of the gate electrode may not be exactly uniform in all directions.

So, if you want two transistors to be matched, use exactly the same size and shape for them. Orient their gates in the same direction. Use the same side of the gate (left/right or top/bottom) to be the drain for the transistor. Keep the transistors close together.